# Worklight common build failing with "Failed to update main HTML file"

Tags: build, ibm-mobilefirst

I have started getting the following all of a sudden and am not able to build and deploy my application all of a sudden.. Not able to figure out what caused this to start happening.

Error:

```
[2013-08-13 12:21:41]FWLST1040E: common build failed: Failed to update main HTML file 'C:\Users\ajay\AppData\Local\Temp\worklightBuildcommon8499642247565272374\preview\default\myapp.html'

[2013-08-13 12:21:41]             Application 'mypp' with all environments build finished.

[2013-08-13 12:21:41] FWLST1035I: No environments to build.
```

The build and deploy is not working and I am not able to update the app in the simulator.. Has any one else faced this before?

Answer (score 2):

@idan thanks for the answer. There is no /worklightBuildcommon* folder in temp.
But I found the problem.. It was a malformed HTML that was causing this error.. the HTML validator that runs never caught it - the fact that its giving a build error was misleading me to believe its a build time problem v/s bad html..

I cracked it by creating a new dummy app in the same project and just replacing the artifacts one at a time.. started with tht html first and hit the jackpot!

Comment: Wow. I don't like that... the fact that there was a build failure because of malformed HTML, and in this fashion. Can you please share with me the complete HTML that caused the error to begin with so that I could reproduce it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to `C:\Users\ajay\AppData\Local\Temp\`
2. delete the folder `worklightBuildcommon8499642247565272374`